# A website that I am trying to scrape is changing tags/IDs based on if it detects a crawler. Is there a way to avoid this?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, user-agent

I am trying to write a basic web scraper that looks through a forum, goes into each post, then checks to see if the post has any github links, storing those links. I am doing this as a part of my research to see how people use and implement Smart Device routines.

I'm fairly new to web scraping, and have been using BeautifulSoup, but I've run into a strange issue. First, my program:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from user_agent import generate_user_agent

url = 'https://community.smartthings.com/c/projects-stories'

headers = {'User-Agent': generate_user_agent(device_type="desktop", os=('linux'))}
page_response = requests.get(url, timeout=5, headers=headers)

page = requests.get(url, timeout = 5)
#print(page.content)
if page.status_code == 200:
    print('URL: ', url, '\nRequest Successful!')
content = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(content.prettify())

project_url = []
for i in content:
    project_url += content.find_all("/div", class_="a href")
print(project_url)
```

What I'm trying to do right now is simply collect all the url links to each individual post on the website. When I try to do this, it returns an empty list. After some experimentation in trying to pick out a specific url based on it's ID, I found that while the ID of each post does not seem to change every time the page is reloaded, it DOES change if the website detects that a scraper is being used. I believe this considering that when the contents of the webpage is printed to the console, at the end of the HTML data, there is a section that reads:

```
  <!-- include_crawler_content? -->
  </div>
  <footer class="container">
   <nav class="crawler-nav" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    <a href="/">
     Home
    </a>
    <a href="/categories">
     Categories
    </a>
    <a href="/guidelines">
     FAQ/Guidelines
    </a>
    <a href="/tos">
     Terms of Service
    </a>
    <a href="/privacy">
     Privacy Policy
    </a>
   </nav>
```

The website seems to detect the crawler and change the navigation based on that. I've tried generating a new user_agent to trick it, but I've had no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: A few options are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53961188/website-blocks-python-crawler-searching-for-idea-to-avoid?rq=1), or there's also browser session automation with Selenium, which can sometimes fare slightly better

Comment: Soo, they have Terms of Service, are actively trying to block scraping and you want to get around that? That doesn't seem to be particularly fair. If you have legitimate research then just mail them and ask for the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially start by using

```
content.findChildren('a')
```

and then go from there, sorting through the results for the links you want.